# Angular 1 js and materialize css

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can i use materialze's plugins like carousel and modal with jqlite(included in angular) instead of the full jquery? I want to build a site user plain js and angular, node js and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the full jQuery library with an Angular app in any HTML page. The order is important here though: include your script tag for jQuery first, then Angular.

The way that angular works is it first checks to see if jQuery is loaded on the page. If it is, then it will use it, otherwise it will use its self-provided jqlite.

The [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) on the issues also warn about versioning issues:

> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.